# Forming a committee

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose a committee must be formed from a group of 15 professors and 10 administrators.
How many committees can be formed if the committee must consist of 5
professors and 5 administrators?

Update 1: Suppose as above that we have 15 professors and 10 administrators to choose from.
Now suppose that we must compose a committee of 4 which must either consist entirely
of professors, or entirely of administrators. How much such committees can be formed?

The answer of Update 1 should be $$\binom{15}{4} +\binom{10}{4}$$
There should be summation because it says Either Or.

Correct me if I'am wrong?

Comment: Now suppose that we must compose a committee of 4 which must either consist entirely of professors, or entirely of administrators. How much such committees can be formed?

Comment: If this is for a course, then presumably you've already been told how to do other problems like this, and any of us answering this question would defeat the purpose of the exercise, which is for _you_ to make the connection between these problems and the ones you've already seen. If this is _not_ for a course, how did it arise?

Comment: I am solving my past papers questions, But i am little weak in combination and permutation thats why i asked.

Comment: I'm mostly concerned with whether you will become any _stronger_ when answers are given with no effort on your part. But perhaps you have already made the effort and simply have not told about it?

Comment: This question is from Discrete Mathematics. What i was hoping from you guys was to provide me an answer so that i know i am doing it correctly. If I don't know the answer how would i know if the solution is correct or not!

Comment: So you _did_ make an effort you did not tell us about? Next time when you already have an answer that you want to check, post your answer as part of the question and ask if it is correct, and we'll know what kind of help to give. The answer could then be as simple as, "Yes, it goes exactly the way you said."

Comment: Yes, Next time I will keep this in my mind, Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We choose $5$ professors out of the $15$, and $5$ administrators out of the $10$. The answer is hence

$$\binom {15}{5}\times\binom{10}{5}$$

Comment: Now suppose that we must compose a committee of 4 which must either consist entirely
of professors, or entirely of administrators. How much such committees can be formed?

Answer (score 0):

We choose $5$ committee members from 15 professors, and $5$ committee members from the 10 administrators.

That gives us $$\binom{15}5 \cdot \binom{10}5$$

possible ways of constructing a committee.